# Get HTML of an ul except certain children

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an ul/li list

```html
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked />
    <a>whatever link1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked />
    <a>whatever link3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <a>whatever link2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
        <a>whatever link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking to get the HTML representing the whole list, only when the checkbox are checked using javascript and/or jquery.

Would anyone by chance have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretending I understand this question exactly, what happens to `whatever link2`, given that it's not checked but contains a checked child?

Comment: could you write your outcome/expectation given that list? not clear if the nested one should be included or not, since its parent is not checked

Comment: Oh sorry, I unecheked the wrong one. Yes I'd like it to be included.

assuming "whatever link 3" is unchecked something like : 
"<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <a>whatever link1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <a>whatever link3</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <a>whatever link2</a>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked />
    <a>whatever link4</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>"
<

Comment: have a look at https://api.jquery.com/find/ in combination with children() - it is all documented

Answer (score 0):

This assigns the html to s.

Not sure what you want to do with it after that.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').onclick (
  if($(this).checked)
    s=$(this).ancestor('#browser').html();
)
```

Comment: If you're not sure, please don't post half an answer

Comment: The answer 'gets the html' as per the OP. What happens next is unstated.

Comment: Not really, it ignores the `only when the checkbox are checked` part completely. See Loktar's answer, posted five minutes before your last comment...

Comment: OK - I can see it was incorrect (correct). But surety is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question fully but here's an example. This only selects a list (so only `whatever link2` will trigger it), however it can be changed to select the anchor if that's necessary.

```js
const mainList = document.getElementById('browser');

mainList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
    const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('li > input:checked ~ ul')];

    const selectedMarkup = document.getElementById('selectedMarkup');
    selectedMarkup.innerHTML = list.map(el => el.innerHTML).join('');
  }
})
```

```html
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked />
    <a>whatever link1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked />
    <a>whatever link3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <a>whatever link2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
        <a>whatever link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

Selected Markup
<div id='selectedMarkup'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to push class on tick of checkbox in li.
e.g onCheck => <li class='checked'>

Then get all element who are having class 'checked' using jquery

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help everyone, I solved it. Every answer helped :)

For reference, my question wasn't clear at all, here what I was trying to do:

```js
var domString = "<ul>";

function run() {
  var mainTree = document.getElementById('browser');
  getDom(mainTree);
  domString += "</ul>";
  console.log(domString);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = domString;
  domString = "<ul>";
}

function getDom(tree) {
  var children = tree.children;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (children[i].className === "list") {
      var liChildren = children[i].children;
      if (liChildren[0].checked == true) {
        domString += children[i].outerHTML;
      }
    } else {
      var liChildren = children[i].children;
      if (liChildren[0].checked == true) {
        domString += "<li class=\"site\">";
        domString += liChildren[0].outerHTML;
        domString += liChildren[1].outerHTML;
        domString += "<ul>";
        getDom(liChildren[2]);
        domString += "</ul>"
        domString += "</li>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
  <li class="list">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <a>whatever link1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" />
    <a>whatever link2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="site">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <a>whatever link3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="list">
        <input class="check" type="checkbox" checked />
        <a>whatever link4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
        <input class="check" type="checkbox" />
        <a>whatever link5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<button onclick="run()">Click</button>
<p>--------------------</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

It's not optimal at all (and ugly at best, syntax wise) but it'll do for now. I'd be interested in hearing others better solutions though.

Have a nice day.